# global.jsp not found in Maven project while using JspC in CQ5 Archtype?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven, aem

I have created multi-module CQ5 Maven project. My Cq version is 5.5 and Java version is 6.

These are the steps that I have followed.

1. Created maven multi-module CQ maven project
2. Imported it in eclipse
3. Used VLT to import an existing project from repository into maven.
4. Converted the project to faceted form so the **bundle** part works fine.
5. In the **content** module I am trying to use JspC Plugin I have added the correct plugin info and dependencies in the respective POM files.

The Problem is that **when I compile JspC says that global.jsp is not found**

So I imported /libs also in my project and made sure that the libs is not included in built. By excluding the /libs folder. I referred this link [Adding /libs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/ht-projects-maven.html#Syncing%20Paths%20Without%20Adding%20Them%20to%20the%20Package)

My JSPs have the default autocomplete feature in them but they don't recognise any CQ objects like the ones defined in `<cq:defineObjects />` **WHY ??**

I referred this Link [Autocomplete in JSP](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/dev-tools/howto-projects-eclipse.html)

**My Directory Structure**

[image]

**My Content POM is as follows**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P A R E N T P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>supplierportal</groupId>
        <artifactId>supplierportal</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- P R O J E C T D E S C R I P T I O N -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->

    <artifactId>supplierportal-content</artifactId>
    <packaging>content-package</packaging>
    <name>Supplier Portal Package</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>supplierportal-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- My Dependencies -->
        <!-- Dependencies for Maven JSPC Starts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.jcr.jcr-wrapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <!-- javax.jcr -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-commons</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <!-- com.day.cq.commons -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-wcm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.2</version>
            <!-- com.day.cq.wcm.commons -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-wcm-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <!-- com.day.cq.wcm.api -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>day-commons-jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.4</version>
            <!-- javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-wcm-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
            <!-- com.day.cq.wcm.tags -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <!-- org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.taglib -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.granite</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.adobe.granite.xssprotection</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.14</version>
            <!-- com.adobe.granite.xss -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.day.cq.wcm</groupId>
            <artifactId>cq-wcm-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.6</version>
            <!-- com.day.cq.wcm.core.components -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <!-- org.apache.commons.lang3 -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Ends -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/content/jcr_root</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/.vlt</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/.vltignore</exclude>
                    <exclude>libs/</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>



        </resources>

    <!-- Autocomplete Plugin config comes here -->
        <!-- THis is Completely different Stuff... An Attempt to bring autocomplete feature in JSP -->
        <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
        <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            <pluginExecutions>
              <pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-jspc-plugin</artifactId>
                  <versionRange>[2.0.6,)</versionRange>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>jspc</goal>
                  </goals>
                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                <action>
                  <ignore/>
                </action>
              </pluginExecution>
              <pluginExecution>
                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                  <versionRange>[2.4.1,)</versionRange>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>clean</goal>
                  </goals>
                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                <action>
                  <ignore/>
                </action>
              </pluginExecution>
            </pluginExecutions>
          </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
        <!-- Autocomplete Ends -->


    <!-- Ends Autocomplete -->
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includeEmptyDirs>true</includeEmptyDirs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <group>supplierportal</group>
                    <filterSource>src/main/content/META-INF/vault/filter.xml</filterSource>
                    <embeddeds>
                        <embedded>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>supplierportal-bundle</artifactId>
                            <target>/apps/supplierportal/install</target>
                        </embedded>
                    </embeddeds>
                    <targetURL>http://${crx.host}:${crx.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Here I add code for JSPc Plugin -->

            <!-- start -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsps-to-compile</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/content/jcr_root</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>libs/**</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jspc-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-jsp</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jspc</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <jasperClassDebugInfo>false</jasperClassDebugInfo>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jsps-to-compile</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/ignoredjspc</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>remove-compiled-jsps</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>
                            <filesets>
                                <fileset>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/jsps-to-compile</directory>
                                    <directory>${project.build.directory}/ignoredjspc</directory>
                                </fileset>
                            </filesets>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end -->

            <!-- Ends JSPC plugin config -->

        </plugins>

    </build>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallPackage</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-content-package</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>autoInstallPackagePublish</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.day.jcr.vault</groupId>
                        <artifactId>content-package-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>install-content-package-publish</id>
                                <phase>install</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>install</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <targetURL>http://${publish.crx.host}:${publish.crx.port}/crx/packmgr/service.jsp</targetURL>
                                    <username>${publish.crx.username}</username>
                                    <password>${publish.crx.password}</password>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it. I imported /libs/foundation in my content part of Maven project. 
Then I added this in the **maven-resources-plugin** configuration

```
<resource>  
      <directory>src/main/content/jcr_root</directory>  
      <includes>  
          <include>apps/**</include>  
          <include>libs/foundation/global.jsp</include>
    </includes>  
  </resource>
```

This configuration includes global.jsp in the compile process, so this helped all my Jsps that had included global.jsp in them to compile successfuly.

But it is also necessary to exclude the libs in the built other wise the whole /libs is included in the built.

To do that we must add this entry in content/pom.xml

```
<build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/content/jcr_root</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/.vlt</exclude>
                    <exclude>**/.vltignore</exclude>
                    <exclude>libs/</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>



        </resources>
```

Comment: I am encountering the same issue, how did you import the /libs/foundation into the content part of maven project? would you be able to provide some details?

Comment: @Vincent firstly please add this entries into your POM file. Secondly to answer your question you'll need to files filter.xml and filter-vlt.xml under META-INF/vault.. Then just use vlt to checkout the code add global.jsp entry in filter-vlt.xml this way it will just be include while compiling but not be a part of package build. Read about these files on Adobe Docs

Answer (score 3):

@Vincent I couldn't answer you question in comments so I am giving you a detailed answer to you comment here.

To  import /lib/foundations you have a create an EXTRA file filter-vlt.xml under

```
{yourproject}\content\src\main\content\META-INF\vault\filter-vlt.xml
```

In **filter-vlt.xml** this you have to enter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/libs/foundation"/>
    <filter root="/apps/myapp"/>
    <filter root="/etc/designs/myapp"/>
     <filter root="/etc/designs/bootstrap-custom-version2"/>
</workspaceFilter>
```

See entry of **/libs/foundation**.

**Make sure you don't put this entry in *filter.xml*. This should be present in *filter-vlt.xml***

And your **filter.xml** entry will be like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<workspaceFilter version="1.0">
    <filter root="/apps/myapp"/>
     <filter root="/etc/designs/myapp"/>
     <filter root="/etc/designs/bootstrap-custom-version2"/>     
</workspaceFilter>
```

i.e the **/libs/foundation** is not present in **filter.xml**

Then browse to `{yourproject}\content\src\main\content\jcr_root` and type

```
vlt up --force
```

This will import you **/apps/myapp** i.e your project into your file system along with
**/libs/foundation** but when you are **building your project /libs/foundation will not be included in the build.**

**Conclusion:**

filter-vlt.xml helps you import files from CQ repo to local drive(file system) that you need for compiling your project. But these files are not included when you do maven build or install into CQ repository(filesystem to CQ repo).

Only those files are pushed into CQ repository whose entry is present in filter.xml

Comment: Hi Oliver, everytime I do that filevault i get this error:

[ERROR] update: org.apache.jackrabbit.vault.vlt.VltException: Directory is not under vault control.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: This normally happens when you do `vlt up --force` and there is no .vlt file present. Please provide more details on what you did and where exactly the error came. @squid267

Comment: I was able to fix it by running this command: vlt --credentials admin:admin up --force http://localhost:4502/crx

Comment: Is there any other way of getting JSP to compile or getting the missing global.jsp?  I dont have vlt installed and when I got that I don't have a running AEM which presumably this needs, accessing a remote one fails,  I'm developing on windoze and running on Linux VMs.  I'd like this to work in Jenkins a remote executing AEM instance is not a nice dependency for a build process.

Comment: @teknopaul you can use package manager to checkout the missing code. create a page and package global.jsp into it. package manager internally uses vlt itself. zip whatever you want and download and use it in your project after unzipping.

Comment: Not sure how to "create a page and package global.jsp into it" AEM 6 crx/de/ has GUI no option to "create page", tried creating various different node types and a node of type cq:Page but then there is no option to package a JSP into the node. I also tried creating a package from an existing JSP that references global and package manager creates a package without the dependencies.